# PostgreSQL materialized views

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I finished my course on Oracle databases and have been playing with it since sometime. One of my friends told me that PostgreSQL is a very good database management system which has object oriented capabilities.

On an Oracle database, it is a straightforward and easy process to create materialized views. BUT despite of having heard that PostgreSQL supports materialized views from few people, I am unable to figure out how to do that.

Please advise.

Comment: Obvious question: why do you *want* materialised views? Why would you need them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For PostgreSQL version **9.2 and below**, read the following article on how to create materialized views by using functions and triggers.

- http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views

---

Since version **9.3**, materialized views are natively supported:

For more information on this topic, please refer to the following articles on PostgreSQL documentation:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rules-materializedviews.html

Comment: +1 for updating your answer to account for the new feature. Wish more people did this.

Answer (score 3):

There's no native support for materialized views in postgres.

You could try to emulate them with triggers/stored procedures as described in [this article](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views).